# Creating A List Application

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple list application for my first app. I have a hello world application running successfully on my droidx2 but when I change the code for a list it gives me a bunch of errors in the code.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

The .java file

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}
```

This code might look familiar to you guys if you looked at a list example on the [android development](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) pages.

Do I need to import certain packages to get this to work?

EDIT: After installing the packages it fixed a lot of errors. I'm stilling getting an error here:   `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));` It doesn't like list_item. I fexed the COUNTRIES problem.

EDIT 2: I figured out the problem. I never created the list_item.xml. Once that is created then the error is gone.

Comment: Give an example of the "bunch of errors", please.

Comment: Yes you need to import the **import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;** But what are the errors?

Comment: In eclipse, try "Cmd+Shift+O" to import all necessary packages. When prompted to specify the package, choose the ones from the Android SDK.

Comment: ok after importing the packages I get an error here: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES)); It doesn't like list_item

Comment: @Jim Lim Your key strokes helped a lot :)

Comment: a little bit of LogCat might be nice ....

Comment: if I knew how I totally would. Sorry I just dove right into creating an app.

Comment: @Marc please close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I never created the list_item.xml. Once that is created then the error is gone.